# Map is always centered in the searched location marker

Tags: react-native, location, google-places

When I put the code: `region={this.props.region}` it works and center the map in the searched location but do not allows to select other markers in the map... it always came back to the searched location, if I take off this part of the code: `region={this.props.region}`, I can select other markers but when I search other location the camera do not move to the chosen location. How proceed in this case?

Here is some code:

```
<MapView
        provider="google"
        style={styles.map}
        //region={this.props.region}
        initialRegion={this.state.focusedlocation}
        ref={ref => (this.map = ref)}>
        {this.renderMarkers()}
        <MapView.Marker
          onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
          coordinate={this.props.region}>
          <Image source={markerImage} style={styles.icon} />
        </MapView.Marker>
      </MapView>
```

Here below is the code to animate to the markers:

```
 pickLocationHandler = event => {
const coords = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;
console.log('Location picker Marker', coords);
this.map.animateToRegion({
  ...this.state.focusedlocation,
  latitude: coords.latitude,
  longitude: coords.longitude,
  latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
  longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
});
```

[Please open this snack to entire code](https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/maps-geoloation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`region` used when you want to control the viewport of map. In your case, you can use `animateCamera` to move the map to your searched location.

```
this.map.animateCamera({
  center: {latitude, longitude}
})
```

### UPDATE

map-view.js

```
export default class MapView extends Component {
  ...
  animateToLocation = (location) => {
    this.map.animateToRegion({
      latitude: location.latitude,
      longitude: location.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    });
  }
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} {...this.props}>
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

map-container.js

```
class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  ...
  getCoordsFromName(loc) { 
    this.map.animateToLocation({
      latitude: loc.lat,
      longitude: loc.lng,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
          <MyMapView ref={ref => this.map = ref} region={this.state.region}/>
          <MapInput style = {{flex: 1, position : 'absolute'}} notifyChange={loc => this.getCoordsFromName(loc)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your project. App works well after disable `region={this.props.region}`. Did you try?

Comment: yeah, i try it, but if i disable it, the camera do not move to searched location... :( any idea?

Comment: Ok, i see. In map-container, you'd like to move to searched location. I suggest you use `ref` from `MyMapView`, then write a function that animate map to a location. So, you can call that function in `map-container`.

Comment: Now works, but the pin image, do not follow the searcj=hed location, open this bellow snack, can you help me?

Comment: need to move the to the region and uodate the searched marker `updateState(location) {
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: location.latitude,
        longitude: location.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      },
    });
  }`

Comment: In `updateState`, you can totally use `this.map.animateToLocation(location)` instead

Comment: `updateState(loc) {
    this.map.animateToLocation({
      ...this.setState({
        region: {
          latitude: loc.latitude,
          longitude: loc.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        },
      }),
    });
  }`

Comment: Hmm, what is the purpose of `region` state? I think you could remove it and rename the function `updateState` to `animateToLocation` to avoid misunderstanding. So the whole function will be `animateToLocation(loc) { this.map.animateToLocation(location) }

Comment: region state is the initial region on the map-container.js, is used just to set a region initial to render the map. i Will  try it, i just need to move the pin marker(searched location) with the code`this.map.animateToLocation(location)`

Comment: in my case I Need to animate the camera and set a pin marker in the searched location, this is possible? I try but not success.. :/

Comment: In the real device, the code: `getCoordsFromName(loc) { 
    this.map.animateToLocation({
      latitude: loc.lat,
      longitude: loc.lng,
    })
  }` closes the app,you have any idea?

Comment: The code not work in the real device, I do not know why, but you are very helpfull tio me, as this reason i will mark this question right! if you have some time, plese see this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033259/how-can-i-render-my-markers-inside-the-clusteredmapview