# How can I render my markers inside the ClusteredMapView?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am trying to render the markers inside the component `<ClusteredMapView/>` but it do not happen, just render the marker with none markers...
Bellow some code:

```
render() {
 return (
  <ClusteredMapView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    data={this.state.data}
    initialRegion={INIT_REGION}
    ref={r => {
      this.map = r;
    }}
    renderMarkerS={this.renderMarkerS}
    renderCluster={this.renderCluster}
   />
  );
 }
}
```

here is the renderMarkers function:

```
renderMarkerS = item =>
this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
  console.log('Location picker Marker', coords);
  const coords = {
    location: {
      latitude: JSON.parse(item.latitude),
      longitude: JSON.parse(item.longitude),
    },
  };
  return (
    <Marker
      onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
      ref={mark => (marker.mark = mark)}
      key={index || Math.random()}
      title={'Parada'}
      description={marker.hora}
      tracksViewChanges={!this.state.initialized}
      {...this.props}
      pinColor={'tomato'}
      coordinate={JSON.parse(item.location)}
      //coordinate={coords}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </Marker>
  );
});
```

With:

```
 componentDidMount() {
return fetch(
  'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MatheusCbrl/bba7db1c0dbc68be2f26d5c7e15649b6/raw/0fab4ea3b493dcd15e95f172cd0a251724efbc45/ParadasDiurno.json'
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    // just setState here e.g.
    this.setState({
      data: responseJson,
      isLoading: false,
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}


My data is:
 [
{
  "id": "1",
  "location": {
    "latitude": "-29.2433828",
    "longitude": "-51.199249"
  },
  "hora": "03:55:00 PM"
},
```

Some one can help me?

Here is the intere code to your view: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/clusters

I got the follow error:

> Device: (3:18096) No cluster with the specified id.
>
> Device: (3:5314) TypeError: t.props.renderMarker is not a function. (In 't.props.renderMarker(e.properties.item)', 't.props.renderMarker' is undefined)
>
> This error is located at:
>       in e
>       in MyClusteredMapView
>       in RCTView
>       in RCTView
>       in n
>       in n
>       in v
>       in RCTView
>       in RCTView
>       in c
>   Device: TypeError: t.props.renderMarker is not a function. (In 't.props.renderMarker(e.properties.item)', 't.props.renderMarker' is undefined)
>   Prettier
>   Editor
>   Expo

Answer (score 1):

`renderMarker` is a function that render just 1 marker. Besides, you use `this.state.data` for markers but you didn't update it. You could try below

```
componentDidMount() {
  return fetch(
  'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MatheusCbrl/bba7db1c0dbc68be2f26d5c7e15649b6/raw/0fab4ea3b493dcd15e95f172cd0a251724efbc45/ParadasDiurno.json'
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    // just setState here e.g.
    this.setState({
      data: responseJson,      <-- update here
      isLoading: false,
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

```
renderCluster = (cluster, onPress) => {
    const pointCount = cluster.pointCount,
        coordinate = cluster.coordinate;
    const clusterId = cluster.clusterId;
    return (
      <Marker key={clusterId} coordinate={coordinate} onPress={onPress}> 
        <View style={styles.myClusterStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.myClusterTextStyle}>
            {pointCount}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </Marker>
    );
};

renderMarker(marker) {
    console.log('Location picker Marker', marker.location);
    const coords = {
      latitude: parseFloat(marker.location.latitude),
      longitude: parseFloat(marker.location.longitude),
    }
    return (
      <Marker
          key={marker.id}
          title={'Parada'}
          description={marker.hora}
          pinColor={'tomato'}
          coordinate={coords}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <ClusteredMapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={this.state.data}
          initialRegion={INIT_REGION}
          ref={r => this.map = r}
          renderMarker={this.renderMarker}
          renderCluster={this.renderCluster}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: here is the error: ***Device: (3:1488) TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.location.longitude')***

Comment: @Matheuscabral Could you post your latest code? The error means somewhere `location` is undefined. You could try to debug or print data to check.

Comment: data is supposed to be an array of objects, each of which is supposed to contain a location attribute representing a GeoPoint. I will try to replace my data prop with the following:

data={[ { location: { latitude: number ,longitude: number } }]}

Comment: I did it look  at the code: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/clusters

Comment: I geting this error: **TypeError: t.props.renderMarker is not a function. (In 't.props.renderMarker(e.properties.item)', 't.props.renderMarker' is undefined)**

Comment: @Matheuscabral your code above contains some errors. First, please update your `renderMarkerS` as above. it must return 1 marker only. Second, you pass wrong props name to `ClusteredMapView`, it must be `renderMarker`, not `renderMarkerS`

Comment: Please, can you add the right code and update the answer?

Comment: Device: (3:18096) No cluster with the specified id. i got this error when i press in the clustered points, some help?

Comment: @Matheuscabral try add `key={clusterId}` in `renderCluster`. Updated answer above.

Comment: Hmm, I have not experienced this issue before. It seems related to this issue https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-maps-super-cluster/issues/52. You can check here for more information. If possible, you could debug inside library itself to see what happens